# How can I add rank or row number into query result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below query which is returning result, but I need to add row number or rank. Working query is following

```
SELECT  user_id, CAST(SUM(total_score) / 100 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS points
FROM users_games 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING points > 500 AND points < 5000
ORDER BY points DESC
```

I tried following for getting row number and rank

```
SET @rank=0; 
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1, user_id, CAST(SUM(total_score) / 100 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS points
FROM users_games
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING points > 500 AND points < 5000
ORDER BY points DESC;
SELECT @rank;
```

Comment: @Andreas I think mysql is correct the rest of them I added mistakenly

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas I found this `Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.4`

Comment: Execute `select version();` to get the version of MySql.

Comment: @forpas yes I got it, it is `10.4.11-MariaDB`

Comment: @forpas I am sorry for giving you wrong db information

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of MySQL and MariaDB, you can use variables:

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1), ug.*
FROM (SELECT  user_id, CAST(SUM(total_score) / 100 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS points
      FROM users_games 
      GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING points > 500 AND points < 5000
      ORDER BY points DESC
     ) ug CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params;
```

Comment: Yes it is working but this one is returning duplicated user_id row

Comment: I am looking unique user_id and sum all points for each user

Comment: @AyazShah . . . It is impossible for this query to duplicate `user_id`s because the underlying query has `group by user_id`.  That means there is one row per `user_id`.